# What is the fastest way of finding sum of two coordinates from two different sets with some criteria?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have two sets as below. What is the best way to find all coordinates one from each set whose sum is atleast H.

```
A = {(x1,y1), (x2,y2),....(xn,yn)}
B = {(p1,q1), (p2,q2),....(pn,qn)}
```

if the answer is (x1,y1) and (p1,q1) then it should meet x1+p1>=H and y1+q1>=H. I need to find out all such coordinates (only count).

Example:

```
A = {(2,3), (1,6), (5,2), (10,1)}
B = {(5,6), (8,4), (3,5), (1,9), (7,7)}
H = 8
Answer: 7
Explanation:
    {
    {(1,6),(8,4)},
    {(1,6),(7,7)},        
    {(2,3),(7,7)},
    {(5,2),(5,6)},
    {(5,2),(7,7)},
    {(10,1),(1,9)},
    {(10,1),(7,7)}
    }
```

**Bruteforce Approach:** I can use two for loops to go through all combination of two sets A and B. But this is O(N^2) solution.

I know another technique in which I can sort set B on x-coordinates. So that from A, I can pick up each x-coordinate   and will check in B for H-x, identifying H-x can be done in long n but from there I need to count one by one to check whether y-coordinate is meeting the condition or not.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Added value for H. Thank you!

Comment: yes all are positive

Comment: First, any coordinate in B that's greater than H gets set to H. In the example (1,9) gets changed to (1,8). Then the question is how many points in B are inside a given rectangle. For the first element of A (2,3), the question is how many points in B are inside the rectangle (6,5) to (8,8). I'm guessing you need a [space partitioning tree like a k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to answer those queries quickly.

Comment: O(N²) is not necessarily a bad complexity because there can indeed by N² solutions. In this case, brute force is optimal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Note that the list of coordinate pairs (shown in the example's explanation) is not the output of the algorithm. The output is a single number: 7. It's not necessary to enumerate all of the pairs to determine the count.

Comment: @user3386109: you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, a range-tree can be used to solve the "dominant point counting", i.e. telling how many points in a 2D set have coordinates `x>a` and `y>b` (see Shamos & Preparata, Computational Geometry, p.40 + Section 2.3.4). After `O(N Log N)` preprocessing time and with `O(N Log N)` storage, a query can be answered in time `O(Log²N)`.

Hence, by trying all points of the second set in turn and using the above data structure to count the point of the first set such that `xj>h-pi`, `yj>h-qi`, you can achieve the global complexity `O(N Log²N)`.